# Room not updating entities with @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)

Tags: android, android-room, android-mvvm

My application uses Google Places API which data I later use to get weather from openweather.
I have a `SearchFragment` with `RecyclerView` where this happens.

Inside `SearchFragment` I observe the list I'm getting:

```
viewModel.predictions.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    citiesAdapter.submitList(it)
}

<...>

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_weather, menu)

        <...>

        searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
        }
    }
```

My `viewModel`:

```
class SearchViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AutocompleteRepository,
    private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    fun provideClient(client: PlacesClient) {
        repository.provideClient(client)
    }

    val searchQuery = MutableStateFlow("")

    private val autocompleteFlow = searchQuery.flatMapLatest {
        repository.getPredictions(it)
    }

    val predictions = autocompleteFlow.asLiveData()

    fun onAddPlace(place: PlacesPrediction, added: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.update(place, added)
            if (added) weatherRepository.addWeather(place)
            else weatherRepository.delete(place)
        }
    }

    fun onDestroy() = viewModelScope.launch {repository.clearDb()}

}
```

Inside `adapter` I bind my items like this:

```
inner class CityViewHolder(private val binding: ItemCityToAddBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.apply {
                btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val place = getItem(position)
                        btnAdd.animate().rotation(if (place.isAdded) 45f else 0f).start()
                        println("Current item state (isAdded): ${place.isAdded}")
                        listener.onAddClick(place, !place.isAdded)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(prediction : PlacesPrediction) {
            binding.apply {
                val cityName = prediction.fullText.split(", ")[0]
                locationName.text = cityName
                fullName.text = prediction.fullText
                btnAdd.animate().rotation(if (prediction.isAdded) 45f else 0f).start()
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `listener` is passed to my adapter as a parameter from my fragment:

```
override fun onAddClick(place: PlacesPrediction, isAdded: Boolean) {
    viewModel.onAddPlace(place, isAdded)
    println("Parameter passed to onClick: $isAdded, placeId = ${place.placeId}")
}

<...>

    val citiesAdapter = CitiesAdapter(this)
```

My `repository`'s `update()` method looks like this:

```
    suspend fun update(place: PlacesPrediction, added: Boolean) =
        database.dao().update(place.copy(isAdded = added))
```

And finally, my `dao`'s `update`:

```
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun update(prediction: PlacesPrediction)
```

This is all tied up on `PlacesPrediction` class, an here it is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "autocomplete_table")
data class PlacesPrediction(
    val fullText: String,
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double,
    val placeId: String,
    val isAdded: Boolean = false
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0

}
```

So, my problem is that `PlacesPrediction`s entries in my database are not getting updated. Actually, the only field I want to update with the code provided above is `isAdded`, but it stays the same after I press `btnAdd` of my list item. I used Android Studio's Database Inspector to verify that.

I tried using `@Insert` instead like so:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(prediction: PlacesPrediction)
```

```
suspend fun update(place: PlacesPrediction, added: Boolean) =
        database.dao().insert(place.copy(isAdded = added))
```

But strangely it only inserts a copy of `place`, the original item I clicked on stays the same.

### Workaround

I get the desired behavior only if I hack my way to it:

```
@Entity(tableName = "autocomplete_table")
data class PlacesPrediction(
    val fullText: String,
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double,
    val placeId: String,
    var isAdded: Boolean = false,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
)
```

```
suspend fun update(place: PlacesPrediction, added: Boolean) =
        database.dao().insert(place.copy(isAdded = added, id = place.id))
```

And I don't like this soution at all. So my question is: how do I make `@Update` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already understood, the generated `copy` method of data classes ignores all members declared outside the constructor. So `place.copy(isAdded = added)` will generate a copy of all constructor parameters, but leave the id as the default 0, meaning a new element should be inserted, instead of updating an existing one.

Now this is my personal opinion:
Having the id as constructor parameter is the most elegant solution, as updates will work out of the box.

However if you dislike it that much, maybe an extension function might help you:

```
inline fun PlacesPrediction.preserveId(copyBuilder: PlacesPrediction.() -> PlacesPrediction): PlacesPrediction{
    val copy = copyBuilder(this)
    copy.id = this.id
    return copy
}

//usage
suspend fun update(place: PlacesPrediction, added: Boolean) =
    database.dao().insert(place.preserveId { copy(isAdded =  added) })
```

Comment: So, basically with REPLACE conflict strategy the behavior of `insert` and `update` queries is identical provided you copy entry's id as well. Ok, thanks for pointing that out! As for my antipathy for this method, it's nothing in particular, I just thought it's a bad practice since it's trivial to forget to copy the id somewhere and deal with the bugs later. 

Is there any way at all to just update it? Is overriding `copy()` an option? Anyway, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "forget to copy the id somewhere"? When mapping the entity to another object or using the data class' `copy` method?

Comment: When using the `copy` method. Imagine a use case, where multiple `viewModels` use the same `dao` to perform database operations. And imagine you forgot to put entity's `id` into some of the `copy` methods you use in your `viewModels`.

Comment: if the id is part of the constructor, `copy` would automatically copy the id as well, unless you explicitely override it